# PHP 5.6 upgrade and special characters

Tags: php, special-characters

I have a website where I've used php to include sections rather than having code be duplicated for each page.
However, recently my webhost upgraded the PHP to 5.6, and now all my Æ, Ø and Å's give me the replacement character (�).
I'm not running any databases, and setting a charset in the html didn't help.

I'm very inexperienced with PHP, so I have no idea how to fix it.
Please, any help would be great!

Comment: What is the encoding of the page? What is the encoding of the original data? Where does it come from?

Comment: The index.php starts with a <?php include> tag, if that matters.

Comment: It does not. But answers to 3 questions above could help.

Comment: Since 5.6 the default value for the [`default_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) configuration setting is `UTF-8`, before that it was an empty string. And PHP uses that as the `charset` part of the `Content-Type` header it outputs by default. So if your pages are _not_ using UTF-8, but a different encoding, then specify that explicitly – either by changing that config value, or by sending the `Content-Type` header with the correct charset from within your scripts yourself.

Comment: Or - preferably - convert your whole site to use UTF-8, which is the de-facto standard for web sites these days anyway. (And if all of this means nothing at all to you, then it is time for you to read up on the basics of character encodings on the web.)

Comment: I'm not sure, I used Notepad. Didn't think of that as the culprit, I'mma check it out asap, thanks!

Comment: All the files have probably been saved in ANSI, but I cannot test them with UTF-8, cause the webhost conveniently decided to not work. Thanks all, I feel fairly dumb for not remembering that was something you did when saving the file :o

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem after upgrading from php 5.5. to 5.6.

Solved it by setting the default_charset to an empty string in my script:

```
ini_set("default_charset", "");
```

Or if you have acceess to php.ini you can set `default_charset = ""` instead.

More info: https://www.saotn.org/php-56-default_charset-change-may-break-html-output/

Comment: Did you try with ISO-8859-1?

Answer (score 5):

PHP 5.6 changes the default value of `default_charset` to `UTF-8`.
The value should better be set.

If the charset of your php files is `ISO-8859-1` (all in the directory) you can easy put a .htaccess File in the root directory:

```
php_value default_charset ISO-8859-1
```

If only some of your files are in ISO-8859-1 you can easy send a header in the first line of the php file (no need for default_charset):

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
?>
```

Or convert the encoding of php textfiles to utf8 and don't change defaults.

Answer (score 2):

For now the best thing to do is to downgrade to PHP 5.5 or 5.4, because of what CBroe explained in his commentary saying that PHP 5.6 now sets default charset as UTF-8 and many websites are still not ready for it. I had the same issue after migrating to a new server, so I downgraded to PHP 5.5 and automatically all the special characters are displaying correctly again. If you're using WHM, use EasyApache to rebuild Apache and then select the desired PHP version when prompted.

I personally think that PHP developers should warn users better, I mean, making it clear that upgrading to version 5.6 can bring special characters issues for non UTF-8 ready websites/applications. What they did just imposing UTF-8 to millions of developers worldwide was too fast or even too radical.

Answer (score 2):

If you have **multi host** web server especially with **older websites** and **multiple languages**, for maximum compatibility with earlier PHP versions like 5.4 just force reset default_charset value in /etc/php.../php.ini:

In the global [PHP] section find this key and edit, or put like this:

```
default_charset = ""
```

This will not force PHP to set UTF-8 charset for all php files, especially older legacy or national encoding like `windows-1251`, `windows-1257`, `iso-8859-1`, `iso-8859-2`, `ISO-8859-13` and similar.

Or if you are developer, sure use Rob's answer and add code directly to you php application `ini_set("default_charset", "");`