# PHP 5.6 ODBC returns a special character array for string values from database?

Tags: special-characters, unixodbc, php-5.6, intersystems-cache

[array result from odbc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UttFB.png) I`m accessing the intersystem cache database via unix odbc and displaying the details in the website (PHP). Recently I have upgraded the PHP to 5.6 version. I`m getting nondisplayable characters (�) for only strings but the numbers and date fields are display correctly. I`m running the website in Apache 2.4 in Debian 8 machine. Intersystem cache database is running in Debian 6 machine.

Note:every time the characters changing randomly.

Comment: Which version of Cache is, and what version PHP was before ?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 5.6 upgrade and special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999374/php-5-6-upgrade-and-special-characters)

Comment: Cache 2008 and php version is 5.3

Comment: @SSH This question is different from that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999374/php-5-6-upgrade-and-special-characters). After upgrade everything(webpages) working fine except if the cache database returns a string value it gives some special characters.

Comment: did you try to do what those answers suggest? (set charset to empty string or ISO-8859-1)

Comment: I did @SSH but no improvement.