# Character encoding issue with PHP5.6 upgrade

Tags: utf-8, php-5.6, iso-8859-1

I'm migrating cakePHP website from 1.2 to the latest version. As an initial step, I've upgraded it from 1.2 to 1.3. To upgrade to the next versions, I need to upgrade PHP version also as the currently used PHP version is 5.3. When I try to upgrade PHP version to 5.6, I'm facing some character encoding issues.

We have a lot of text come from PHP files. An example text is shown below:

> För att kunna logga in måste du ange ditt användarnamn (e-mail) och ditt 8-siffriga lösenord.

Now it shows like this:

> F�r att kunna logga in m�ste du ange ditt anv�ndarnamn (e-mail) och ditt 8-siffriga l�senord.

I've changed the charset to utf-8. But this didn't help. I've tried to fix this with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999374/php-5-6-upgrade-and-special-characters/33575764). But this affects the strings come from the database.

If I use utf8_encode or iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8") with the text, it shows correctly. Should I need to display each and every text with utf8_encode function? Is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by saving the template files in UTF-8 format.